# Counting the number of True Booleans in a Python List

Tags: python, list, boolean, counting

I have a list of Booleans:

```
[True, True, False, False, False, True]
```

and I am looking for a way to count the number of `True` in the list (so in the example above, I want the return to be `3`.)  I have found examples of looking for the number of occurrences of specific elements, but is there a more efficient way to do it since I'm working with Booleans? I'm thinking of something analogous to `all` or `any`.

Answer (score 289, accepted):

`True` is equal to `1`.

```
>>> sum([True, True, False, False, False, True])
3
```

Comment: That is not idiomatic and makes "abuse" of the type coercion of bool.

Comment: @Jan Segre, there's no coercion, bool is an integer type.

Comment: @panda-34, I checked and `issubclass(bool, int)` in fact holds, so there is no coercion.

Answer (score 241):

`list` has a [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method:

```
>>> [True,True,False].count(True)
2
```

This is actually more efficient than `sum`, as well as being more explicit about the intent, so there's no reason to use `sum`:

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: x = [random.choice([True, False]) for i in range(100)]

In [3]: %timeit x.count(True)
970 ns ± 41.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit sum(x)
1.72 µs ± 161 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: I can't count False values if there is 0 value also

Comment: You can't use `sum` of the other answer if you have other "true" values besides 1 or True either.  Besides, then question didn't mention anything but `True` or `False`.

Comment: Although not the OPs intent, I think it's worth pointing out that `sum` works on other types (e.g. generators) while `count` does not.

Answer (score 49):

If you are only concerned with the constant `True`, a simple `sum` is fine.  However, keep in mind that in Python other values evaluate as `True` as well.  A more robust solution would be to use the `bool` builtin:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, True, False]
>>> sum(bool(x) for x in l)
3
```

UPDATE: Here's another similarly robust solution that has the advantage of being more transparent:

```
>>> sum(1 for x in l if x)
3
```

P.S. Python trivia: `True` *could* be true without being 1.  Warning: do not try this at work!

```
>>> True = 2
>>> if True: print('true')
... 
true
>>> l = [True, True, False, True]
>>> sum(l)
6
>>> sum(bool(x) for x in l)
3
>>> sum(1 for x in l if x)
3
```

Much more evil:

```
True = False
```

Comment: Ok, I see your example, and I see what it's doing. Apart from the LOL-ness of it, is there actually a good reason to do what you've shown here?

Comment: Yes, for the top part. As I indicated, the Python test for a "true " (as in an `if` statement) is more complicated than just testing for `True`.  See http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#truth.  The `True = 2` was just to reinforce that the concept of "true" is more complex; with a little bit of extra code (i.e. using `bool()`) you can make the solution more robust and more general.

Comment: In Python 3, `True` and `False` are keywords and you can't change them.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `sum()`:

```
>>> sum([True, True, False, False, False, True])
3
```

Answer (score 7):

After reading all the answers and comments on this question, I thought to do a small experiment.

I generated 50,000 random booleans and called `sum` and `count` on them.

Here are my results:

```
>>> a = [bool(random.getrandbits(1)) for x in range(50000)]
>>> len(a)
50000
>>> a.count(False)
24884
>>> a.count(True)
25116
>>> def count_it(a):
...   curr = time.time()
...   counting = a.count(True)
...   print("Count it = " + str(time.time() - curr))
...   return counting
... 
>>> def sum_it(a):
...   curr = time.time()
...   counting = sum(a)
...   print("Sum it = " + str(time.time() - curr))
...   return counting
... 
>>> count_it(a)
Count it = 0.00121307373046875
25015
>>> sum_it(a)
Sum it = 0.004102230072021484
25015
```

Just to be sure, I repeated it several more times:

```
>>> count_it(a)
Count it = 0.0013530254364013672
25015
>>> count_it(a)
Count it = 0.0014507770538330078
25015
>>> count_it(a)
Count it = 0.0013344287872314453
25015
>>> sum_it(a)
Sum it = 0.003480195999145508
25015
>>> sum_it(a)
Sum it = 0.0035257339477539062
25015
>>> sum_it(a)
Sum it = 0.003350496292114258
25015
>>> sum_it(a)
Sum it = 0.003744363784790039
25015
```

And as you can see, `count` is 3 times faster than `sum`. So I would suggest to use `count` as I did in `count_it`.

Python version: 3.6.7
CPU cores: 4
RAM size: 16 GB
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness' sake (`sum` is usually preferable), I wanted to mention that we can also use `filter` to get the truthy values. In the usual case, `filter` accepts a function as the first argument, but if you pass it `None`, it will filter for all "truthy" values. This feature is somewhat surprising, but is well documented and works in both Python 2 and 3.

The difference between the versions, is that in Python 2 `filter` returns a list, so we can use `len`:

```
>>> bool_list = [True, True, False, False, False, True]
>>> filter(None, bool_list)
[True, True, True]
>>> len(filter(None, bool_list))
3
```

But in Python 3, `filter` returns an iterator, so we can't use `len`, and if we want to avoid using `sum` (for any reason) we need to resort to converting the iterator to a list (which makes this much less pretty):

```
>>> bool_list = [True, True, False, False, False, True]
>>> filter(None, bool_list)
<builtins.filter at 0x7f64feba5710>
>>> list(filter(None, bool_list))
[True, True, True]
>>> len(list(filter(None, bool_list)))
3
```

Answer (score 3):

It is safer to run through `bool` first. This is easily done:

```
>>> sum(map(bool,[True, True, False, False, False, True]))
3
```

Then you will catch everything that Python considers True or False into the appropriate bucket:

```
>>> allTrue=[True, not False, True+1,'0', ' ', 1, [0], {0:0}, set([0])]
>>> list(map(bool,allTrue))
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

If you prefer, you can use a comprehension:

```
>>> allFalse=['',[],{},False,0,set(),(), not True, True-1]
>>> [bool(i) for i in allFalse]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `len([b for b in boollist if b is True])` (or the generator-expression equivalent), as it's quite self-explanatory. Less 'magical' than the answer proposed by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams.

Alternatively, you can do this, which still assumes that bool is convertable to int, but makes no assumptions about the value of True:
`ntrue = sum(boollist) / int(True)`

Comment: Your solution has at least two problems.  One, it suffers from the same robustness issue; that you could fix by just changing the test to  `if b`.  But, more importantly, you are constructing a throwaway list requiring all values to be in memory at once and you can't use `len` with a generator expression.  Better to avoid such practices so that the solution can scale.

Comment: @Ned Deily :`if b` is exactly wrong. It would only be correct if the question was about items that evaluate as True, rather than actual True booleans. I take your second point though. In that case there's the variant `sum(1 if b is True else 0 for b in boollist)`.

Comment: As I noted elsewhere, it's not clear to me from the question whether the OP really means to count only objects of type bool with the value 1 or means the larger and generally more useful set of values that evaluate true.  If the former, then an identity test is the right approach but it's also limiting.  Objects of type bool are rather odd ducks in Python anyway, a relatively recent addition to the language.  In any case I'd go for the simpler: `sum(1 for b in boollist if b is True)`