# How do I undo True = False in python interactive mode?

Tags: python, boolean, python-2.x

So I tried the "evil" thing Ned Deily mentioned in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765833/counting-the-number-of-true-booleans-in-a-python-list/12766000#12766000). Now I have that the type True is now always False. How would I reverse this within the interactive window?

Thing to not do:

```
True = False
```

Since True has now been completely overridden with False, there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to back-track. Is there a module that True comes from that I can do something like:

```
True = <'module'>.True
```

Comment: All this does is create a local variable named `True`, which hides the builtin constant.  The "real" `True` is unaffected, and can still be created e.g. with `(1 == 1)` or the `bool()` function.  It also lives in `__builtins__.True`.

Comment: Note that this is not possible in Python 3, which treats `True` and `False` as keywords.

Comment: I think you can still use `True = not False` or in this case also `True = not True` to recover. Otherwise, as stated in an answer below, use `del True` to recover the old value.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can simply [`del`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-del_stmt) your custom name to set it back to the default:

```
>>> True = False
>>> True
False
>>> del True
>>> True
True
>>>
```

Comment: So the `True = False` command actually creates a new, local name that shadows the keyword, rather than actually replacing a variable? And this just cleans it up?

Comment: @jpmc26 - Yes, that is correct.  Note however that `True` and `False` are not keywords in Python 2.x; they are builtins.  That is why this is possible.  In Python 3.x, where `True` and `False` *are* keywords, `True = False` would raise a syntax error because you cannot assign to a keyword.

Comment: Interesting to note that this fails if `__builtins__.True` has been changed, as hinted at in the answer from @simonwo.

Comment: @figs - Yea, `del` will not work if you've modified `__builtins__`.  In that case, it would be best to do `True = 1 == 1` like Roberto Bonvallet proposed.  Of course, if you are already going so far as to modify `__builtins__`, then you could also do `del __builtins__` and really ruin the interpreter.  At some point, it might be best to just restart it instead of trying to repair it piecemeal. :)

Comment: @iCodez del assignment

Comment: `del` works to recover other builtins too, `list` being a common one to accidentally shadow when mucking around.

Answer (score 47):

This works:

```
>>> True = False
>>> True
False
>>> True = not False
>>> True
True
```

but fails if `False` has been fiddled with as well. Therefore this is better:

```
>>> True = not None
```

as `None` cannot be reassigned.

These also evaluate to `True` regardless of whether `True` has been reassigned to `False`, `5`, `'foo'`, `None`, etc:

```
>>> True = True == True   # fails if True = float('nan')
>>> True = True is True
>>> True = not True or not not True
>>> True = not not True if True else not True
>>> True = not 0
```

Comment: As much as I like this, I think iCodez's is the more general solution to these override type issues.

Comment: Especially since this falls apart if you do `True, False = False, True` instead.

Comment: @Kevin `True, False = not True, True` fixes that. As long as you have a reference to either `True` or `False` you can deduce the other it seems.

Comment: @figs in fact, if you've done `True, False = False, True`, you can just do it again, and you'll be back to the same place.

Comment: `True == True` will not work if `True` has been redefined to be `float('nan')`: `True == True → False`

Comment: @sebleblanc However, `True is True` does return `True` even then (though `float('nan') is float('nan')` is still `False`).

Comment: Right. `1 == 1` works too, and `False = 2 + 2 == 5`.

Answer (score 37):

Another way:

```
>>> True = 1 == 1
>>> False = 1 == 2
```

Comment: That's a pretty creative, yet simple solution. I'm impressed.

Answer (score 17):

For completeness: Kevin mentions that you could also fetch the real `True` from `__builtins__`:

```
>>> True = False
>>> True
False
>>> True = __builtins__.True
>>> True
True
```

But that `True` can also be overriden:

```
>>> __builtins__.True = False
>>> __builtins__.True
False
```

So better to go with one of the other options.

Answer (score 11):

Just do this:

```
True = bool(1)
```

Or, because booleans are essentially integers:

```
True = 1
```

Comment: `bool = int`. Oops! `bool(1) → 1`.

Comment: @sebleblanc I meant that they work in the same way

Comment: And I mean that your answer does not work in all cases, in the same way that figs and simonwo's answers have pitfalls. If bool was also redefined, you cannot get the value `True` from that function.

Comment: On the other hand, if you don't explicitly need the True or False values, `True = 1` is a foolproof way of getting boolean-like behaviour.

Comment: `True = 1` violates some essential properties, e.g. check `type()`.

Answer (score 2):

Solutions that use no object literals but are as durable as `1 == 1`. Of course, you can define False once True is defined, so I'll supply solutions as half pairs.

```py
def f(): pass
class A(): pass
True = not f()
False = A != A
```

```py
False = not (lambda:_).__gt__(_)
True = not (lambda:_).__doc__
```