# How to fix redefinition of str?

Tags: python, string

Experimenting with the Python interpreter, I unwittingly assigned a string to `str` as follows:

```
str = 'whatever'
```

Later in the same session I entered another statement with a call to [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str), say...

```
double_whatever = str(2) + ' * whatever'
```

..., and got the error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` (instead of the expected output `'2 * whatever'`).  A [related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6039623/1810429) helped me to quickly see the mistake I made.

However,  I am still unclear how to fix calls to `str()` in the affected session.  Of course I could exit the Python interpreter and start another session, but I am curious how to avoid that.

So far I have confirmed that...

```
double_whatever = __builtins__.str(2) + ' * whatever'  # => '2 * whatever'
```

...still works like I want; but I am unclear how to get back to not needing the `__builtins__.` qualification.

*How can I fix my unintentional redefinition of `str` so that my calls to `str()` in the Python-interpreter session work again?*

Comment: This recent SO answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30563742/3923281

Comment: Thanks.  That looks spot-on, `str` not being the only candidate for the mistake it seems.  I was actually working through an ORA online course that had me assign to `str`...and must have assumed a new session for each lecture. :P

Comment: not the best, but quite trivial: `str = __builtins__.str`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Yes, indeed.  I tinkered with something close...and now see why it failed.  I tried `str = __builtins__.str()`, which of course is not the same; but your suggestion was my intent.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just delete your overriding `str`:

```
del str
```

Read http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html for an explanation of how Python finds a variable for you.

The basic idea is that the namespace where you define variables is searched first, so if you define a variable with the name `str`, the `built-in` one is overridden.

Comment: you beat me to earning a few easy points. :)

Comment: @Pynchia Let me share one upvote with you ;)

Comment: I am glad that my relative inexperience with Python could make for such sport. :)  I have never come across the `del` keyword, and [it is a little odd](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6146963/1810429) to me based on more experience with other languages (but I guess no more odd than the ability to redefine built-in functions in JS): this worked perfectly as I am sure you quite confidently expected.  Thanks!

Comment: @satoru: thank you, but it's fine. You deserve it. I am sure I am not the only one who was about to click and.. laughed. I love SO for these things. :)

Comment: maybe, given @J0e3gan comment, you could expand your answer and explain why that works (namespace, etc.)

Comment: @Pynchia OK, let me have a try.

Comment: @J0e3gan I've updated the answer and add a link to a related chapter from Dive into Python.

Comment: Interestingly, much like I had tried something similar to Karoly Hovath's suggestion but not quite right, I had also tried something conceptually similar to `del str` but wrong: `str = None`!  I distinctly sensed it would not work...but was familiar with `None`, had a mentalese self-dialog like, "...just want to *delete* that (`str`) var", and was bothered enough to try (as if there was any risk).  Now I see that [`= None` is apparently not an uncommon awkward temptation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6146963/1810429) in this sort of situation.  What a great learning experience.  Thanks again.