# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable?

Tags: python, pyscripter

I've never programmed in Python before, and I've taken some examples of the internet and edited them a bit to create a code that finds prime numbers. However, even after consulting people who know quite a bit of Python, I can't figure out what the problem with this code is. I always just get the error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

for this line:

```
      if (j > i/j) : print(i, " is prime")
```

Here's the full code for the program.

```
i = 2
while(i < 100):
   j = 2
   while(j <= (i/j)):
      if not(i%j): break
      j = j + 1
      if (j > i/j) : print(i, " is prime")
   i = i + 1
```

Comment: You appear to have assigned a string to the name `print`.

Comment: The dupe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591182/how-to-fix-redefinition-of-str?lq=1) refers to overshadowing of the `str` builtin, It's the same case with `print`. Refer to Martijn's answer to solve your *exact* problem and the dupe to gain some insight.

Answer (score 2):

Elsewhere in your code or session, you bound a string object to the name `print`:

```
print = 'foo'
```

Now `print(...)` is trying to call a string instead of the built-in function.

In an interactive session, delete the name `print`:

```
del print
```

In a script, make sure you don't mask the name `print`; pick a different name for that variable.