# How to print a string and integer variable together?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written the following script:

```
string="My name"
age=19
print(string +str(age))
```

But this gives an error stating:

```
"str object is not callable".
```

Help me to typecast and print.

Comment: Are you sure that's your exact code? Because that should do exactly what you want.

Comment: you've assigned to `str` someplace. do `del str` first and try again.

Comment: @ayhan please dup it as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591182/how-to-fix-redefinition-of-str?noredirect=1&lq=1, I can't since I already voted to close as typo.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Yes, this is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments, it looks like you have re-assigned the built in function `str` to something else. Find and remove that, and your code should work.

It's also worth noting that in `python3` the `print()` function will attempt to cast your arguments to strings if you separate them with a `,`. As seen here:

```
print(string, age)
```

Will cast `age` to a string for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try [formatting strings](https://pyformat.info/):

`print( f'{string} {age}' )`

Comment: That's a format I've never seen before, and I don't see it described in your link.

Comment: I don't think it's the best idea to suggest format strings, new in Python 3.6, to a new user that is most likely not using the most recent release of Python.

Comment: We always can suggest new user to install python 2.7, and use old version first. But you have a point!

Answer (score 0):

String.format can help here.

```
print ("{0} {1}".format(string, age) )
```

this results is the following being printed.

```
My name 19
```

You can use this method to improve the readability of the output as well.

```
print ("Name: {0} age: {1}".format(string, age)
```

This would result in the following output.

```
Name: My Name age: 19
```