# Get length of True values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Doing the length gives me the count of elements:

```
>>> len([False, True, True, False, False])
5
```

However, I'd like to get the number of `True` elements. What would be the best way to do this? Currently I'm doing:

```
>>> len([item for item in items if item is True])
2
```

Perhaps there was a built-in though, something like:

```
len(items, val=False)
```

Comment: Call `sum()` on the list without the list comprehension

Comment: @user2357112  - take that one:  [counting-the-number-of-true-booleans-in-a-python-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765833/counting-the-number-of-true-booleans-in-a-python-list/12766783)  - far better dupe

Comment: @user2357112 bracing for me to be wrong, but I don't agree with the dupe. This is just counting bools.

Comment: @PatrickArtner: `sum` is slower and less clear, so I think `count` is better.

Comment: @user2357112 perhaps you can add an answer that shows that count is faster in a benchmark, comparing the two?

Comment: @roganjosh: Yes, it's counting bools, so a counting dupe is appropriate. The True-specific dupe just promotes a less general, less efficient approach.

Comment: @user2357112 Well, I think that alone should be reason to reopen, or close with a better dupe with timings, because we've all thrown the same suggestion down. It's clearly not common knowledge

Comment: @user2357112 or actually, we've all picked up this idea from some source. I swear I didn't imagine the approach, so something is suggesting this...

Comment: @user2357112 https://stackoverflow.com/a/12765840/4799172 there we go :/ Patrick has linked it in his answer, though, maybe no need to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply sum() the list `False` is 0, `True` is 1. 
Other way would be to `list.count()` the `True`'s:

```
prep = """import random
random.seed("count is faster then sum he said...")
data = random.choices([True,False],k=10000)"""

prog1 = "k = sum(data)"
prog2 = "l = data.count(True)"
prog3 = "j = len( [x for x in data if x] )"

import timeit

print(timeit.timeit(prog1,setup=prep, number = 1000))
print(timeit.timeit(prog2,setup=prep, number = 1000))
print(timeit.timeit(prog3,setup=prep, number = 1000))
```

Output:

```
0.32247100600034173  # sum( data )
0.12246353499995166  # data.count( True )  
0.24579112000083114  # len( [x for x in data if x] )
```

Counting seems to be the right choice, its takes only about 45-50% of the time. Even the list-comp of `len( [x for x in data if x] )` is faster than the sum.

Both methods are already covered in other questions:

- [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)
- [Counting the number of True Booleans in a Python List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765833/counting-the-number-of-true-booleans-in-a-python-list/12766783)

Comment: The second link appears to have affected a lot of people :)

Comment: @Patrick -- great answer. Thank you.