# Why should I use sum() instead of count() to find the null values in a Dataset (Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, anaconda

df.isnull().count()

Output - 740 (Displaying the opposite)

df.isnull().sum()

Output - 8  (Displaying the null values)

PS : 'df' is the name of my dataset

Comment: `pd.Series([True,False]).sum()` gives the sum of the True (boolean) whereas `pd.Series([True,False]).count()` counts all the values True and False hence you get the full count of the length of the dataframe not only the count of True

Comment: @anky, Thanks a ton !

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765833/counting-the-number-of-true-booleans-in-a-python-list