# Is there a Python function which can count the number of sheep in an array?

Tags: python, arrays

Consider an array/list of sheep where some sheep may be missing from their place. We need a function that counts the number of sheep present in the array (true means present).

For example,

```
[True,  True,  True,  False,
  True,  True,  True,  True ,
  True,  False, True,  False,
  True,  False, False, True ,
  True,  True,  True,  True ,
  False, False, True,  True]
```

The correct answer would be 17.

This is what I tried:

```
def count_sheeps(sheep):
    total = 0
    for i in sheep:
        if i == 'True':
            total += i
        else:
            return None
```

This code throws up an error saying that None should equal 17.

Comment: Drop the `else` part, you don't need to do anything if `i` is false.  When the `for` loop is finished, `return total`.

Comment: Also need to compare to `i is True`, not `i == 'True'`. But you can do it much more elegantly: `sheeps.count(True)`.

Comment: `True` is also `1`. You could just `sum(sheep)`.

Comment: Wait a second, is that `True` or `"True"`? Make sure this is a working example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the number of True Booleans in a Python List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765833/counting-the-number-of-true-booleans-in-a-python-list)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are comparing `bool` with `str`.

You can use `if i:`.

BTW, If you want to count the `True`s in your list, you can use `sum` as `True` is 1:

```py
sum([True, False, True, True])
>> 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `"True"` is a string. You can not compare it with a `bool` type:

```py
var1 = True
var2 = "True"

print(var1, type(var1)) # True <class 'bool'>
print(var2, type(var2)) # True <class 'str'>
```

So you could say: `if i is True`. Or because you're only dealing with True and False, you could say `if i`. (Don't forget to return the `total` from your function.

```py
lst = [True, False, True]

def count_sheeps(sheep):
    total = 0
    for i in sheep:
        if i:
            total += i
    return total

print(count_sheeps(lst))
```

That explained your problem, but `list` class has implemented `.count` method which can count the item you pass it:

```py
lst = ["a", "b", "a"]
print(lst.count("a"))
```

Moreover, `bool` is a subclass of `int`, `True` is considered `1` and `False` is considered `0`. So you could also use `sum()`:

```py
def count_sheeps(sheep: list[bool]):
    return sum(sheep)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def count_sheep(array):
    return array.count("sheep")
```

example:

```py
animals = ["sheep", "cow", "sheep", "chicken", "sheep"]
print(count_sheep(animals))  # Output: 3
```

Comment: There is no `"sheep"` item inside the OP's list. They are True and False.